# Diagonalisation of Square Matrices

Tags: matrices

When does a matrix ${\bf A}$ have a similar diagonal matrix and when does it not? I have a matrix ${\bf A}$:

\begin{pmatrix}
  4 & 1\\
  3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

and I am trying to find a matrix ${\bf P}$ such that ${\bf A = P^{-1}\Lambda P}$ where ${\bf \Lambda}$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of A. I was told that ${\bf P}$ is a matrix with the eigenvectors of A in each column.

So I have ${\bf \Lambda}$ as:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}

and hence ${\bf P}$:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  -3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

and hence ${\bf P^{-1}}$:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1/4 & -1/4\\
  3/4 & 1/4
\end{pmatrix}

However this does not satisfy the equality ${\bf A = P^{-1}\Lambda P}$. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You have your matrices switched a little bit. It's
$\mathbf A = \mathbf P\mathbf \Lambda\mathbf  P^{-1}$
or
$\mathbf \Lambda = \mathbf P^{-1}\mathbf A\mathbf P,$
not
$$\mathbf \Lambda = \mathbf P\mathbf A\mathbf P^{-1},$$
as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

In your setup it is true that $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$. If you want the $P^{-1}$ to be on the left then $P^{-1}$ will have to be the matrix with eigenvectors of $A$ as its columns.

Answer (score 2):

An $n \times n$ matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.   In particular, this is true if there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues.